# flashplayer on infokiosk application

Tags: flash, licensing, embedded, adobe

I have to build a series of information kiosks and I was considering using flash technology. However, the Adobe license prohibits redistributing the flashplayer with embedded projects. Does anyone had experience with Adobe with similar projects? Is there a commercial license for the player?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any reason you couldn't just have the kiosks running Firefox/Chrome in kiosk mode loading Flash via the plugin instead of directly embedding it?

Comment: as far as I understand the EULA this is also prohibited

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the embedded player means an actual embedded player and not a copy with a browser. This comes from the fact that the commercial license purchase option is for Flash Lite (see below) which is for Mobile Devices and actually embedded.

I built a Kiosk application back in 2001 without any problem and it looks like there is still no problem as long as it is regular Flash Player with a browser.

**Here is the summary for Flash Player 10**

You may post Adobe Flash Player on company intranet sites or local networks. You may also distribute the Players on a CD, DVD, or any other physical media within the terms and conditions of the electronic Player Distribution License Agreement.

Please note:  Royalty-free Flash Player distribution is limited to specific desktop and laptop operating systems. Distribution restrictions are specified in the license agreement. Distribution on devices is subject to a licensing fee and different licensing terms.  Please contact an Adobe Mobile & Devices representative if you are interested in licensing Flash Player for distribution on devices.

Here is a brief summary of the rights granted by this license:

```
* Licensee is permitted to distribute Adobe Web Players to multiple clients in a closed intranet environment.
* Licensee is permitted to distribute Adobe Web Players to multiple end-users by including the Player installers on CDs, DVDs or other physical media.
* Usage of Adobe Web Players is only permitted for supported platforms; usage rights on non-PC devices or embedded systems are not granted by this license.
* Licensee must use the installers as-is without modification.
* Licensees, at their discretion, are entitled to display the Flash Enabled and/or Shockwave logos on products or intranet sites according to the Style Guide.
```

For a commercial license see: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=flashlite
but it appears this is just for Flash Lite (for mobile devices).

Full License: http://www.adobe.com/products/clients/all_dist_agreement.html

Comment: WOW! Thanks for the answer. You are well documented. I wonder if this applies to projector files too?